# Responsive navigation disappear after open and close and resize to large screen

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, nav

I still don't have a solution can anyone help me with this must be easy. I think that the solution must be find in the javascript and not the media query, because that didn't work for me.

I got a responsive navigation that shows a nav-btn when screen is smaller than 1000px, but after using the nav-btn open+close the menu items disappear when resizing screen width, the horizontal menu items need to return in the place, but because of the js the menu-items disappear.

You see it when resize the screen so you see 4 menu items horizontal inline and when smaller than 1000px you see the responsive menu after open and close and resize the screen larger than 1000px 3 of the 4 menu-items are gone.

```
$(function() {
$('.nav-btn').click(function(event) {
    $('nav ul').fadeToggle(300);
});
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/wz8vc0yo/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved it using `CSS` @media anotation:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    // your needed style here
}
```

Also if you have different sizes / needs check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

**IMPORTANT**: to me I need to define ALL sizes to have correct behaviour when we have transitions in screen size, so to avoid weird things you must define something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    /* COMPUTER STYLES HERE */
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 768px) { 
    /* TABLET STYLE HERE */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* MOBILE PHONE STYLE HERE */
}
```

Comment: I did the same, but it does not respond and show the menu items again. I will try again maybe i did something wrong.

Comment: Weird no response i thought that would be it when i thought of it the first time

Comment: Thanks Jordi good advice will use that, but it still doesn't to get the menu. Do see it happening when using the fiddle? Resize screen so you see the nav-btn open + close and than resize again you only see the 'untitled'.

Comment: Anyone can help with this?